# Escoger el primer hijo de un elemento con JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tengo este código en JavaScript usando jQuery:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $("label").each(function() {
  label = $(this).val();
  label2 = $(this);
  if (label2.$(':first-child')) {
    label.show();
  } else {
    label.hide();
  }
  }) 
})
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.3.slim.min.js" integrity="sha256-ZwqZIVdD3iXNyGHbSYdsmWP//UBokj2FHAxKuSBKDSo=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div class="col-2">
  <label>
    Nombres y Apellidos</br> 
    <input placeholder="Escriba sus nombres" id="nombre" name="nombre" tabindex="1" >
    <input placeholder="Escriba sus apellidos" id="apellido" name="apellido" tabindex="2" >
    </label>  
</div>
<div class="col-3">
  <label>
  Libreta Militar<br><br>
    <label for="">
      <label  for="rta">¿Tiene libreta militar?</label></td>
      <select  name="rta" id="rta" tabindex="5" >
        <option value="0">Escoja la opcion</option>
        <option value="si">Si</option>
        <option value="no">No</option>
      </select>
    </label> 
    <select name="tipo" id="tipo" tabindex="6">
      <option value="0">Escoja el tipo</option>
      <option value="primera clase">Primera Clase</option>
      <option value="segunda clase">Segunda Clase</option>
    </select>
    <input placeholder="Escriba su número de libreta militar" id="libreta" name="libreta" tabindex="7" >
  </label>
</div>
```

Al principio usé el cóodigo para mostrar o no mostrar lo que necesitaba por medio del uso de `id`, pero quiero intentar hacer un código mas global.

Lo ideal es escoger cada primer hijo de cada etiqueta `<label>` y mostrarlo y el resto de hijos esconderlos, solo que no funciona el código que coloqué al principio.

¿Qué otra forma podría utilizar para hacer eso?

Comment: En JQuery se utilizan las mismas llamadas a elementos que en css, es decir, para un elemento se coge por el id con $('#id') o la clase $('.class') normalmente, aunque existen más formas de llamar a un elemento. En su caso puede llamar al elemento que contiene los label por su id y decir que coja al primer hijo tal que así: $('#id_label:first-child') cambiando id_label por el label del que quiera coger el primer hijo. Recuerda que puedes hacerlo por clase, id o cualquier otro método de selección CSS. Si no he entendido bien le agradecería que me lo explicase un poco, no lo termino de entender.

Comment: La idea esta bien pero tengo una pregunta, se puede escoger todos lo label del formulario, por ejemplo escribir $('label:first-child') ?

Comment: Claro, es una forma de selección css pero si tienes más de un label puede que no se haga en el que quieras o que se haga en todos, personalmente me gusta llamarlos por el id.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Comenzaré explicándote los fallos que estás cometiendo en tu código y después te sugeriré cómo hacerlo de manera correcta.

**Muestras y ocultas un valor**

En tu código estás definiendo la variable `label` como el valor de una etiqueta (que siempre es una cadena de caracteres):

```
label = $(this).val();
```

Y después tratas de hacer uso de los métodos `hide()` y `show()` sobre dicha cadena de caracteres, lo que provocará el error:

> label.show is not a function

**Llamar al método `$` de un recurso jQuery**

Estás llamando al método `$` de un recurso jQuery:

```
label2.$(':first-child')
```

Lo que te lanzará el mensaje:

> label2.$ is not a function

Para buscar hijos de un elemento deberás hacer uso de [`child()`](https://api.jquery.com/children/) o [`find()`](https://api.jquery.com/find/).

**Uso correcto de selectores**

No es necesario hacer uso de JavaScript ni jQuery para realizar lo que deseas, basta con crear estos dos estilos CSS para que los elementos aparezcan o desaparezcan dependiendo de si son o no el primer hijo de un elemento `<label>`:

```
label > :first-child {
  display: block;
}

label > :not(:first-child) {
  display: none;
}
```

El primer selector coincidirá con los primeros hijos de una etiqueta `<label>`, mostrando su contenido.

El segundo selector coincidirá con todos los hijos que no sean los primeros, ocultándolos.

Aquí tienes la solución propuesta:

```css
label > :first-child {
  display: block;
}

label > :not(:first-child) {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-2">
  <label>
    Nombres y Apellidos<br> 
    <input placeholder="Escriba sus nombres" id="nombre" name="nombre" tabindex="1" >
    <input placeholder="Escriba sus apellidos" id="apellido" name="apellido" tabindex="2" >
    </label>  
</div>
<div class="col-3">
  <label>
  Libreta Militar<br><br>
    <label for="">
      <label  for="rta">¿Tiene libreta militar?</label></td>
      <select  name="rta" id="rta" tabindex="5" >
        <option value="0">Escoja la opcion</option>
        <option value="si">Si</option>
        <option value="no">No</option>
      </select>
    </label> 
    <select name="tipo" id="tipo" tabindex="6">
      <option value="0">Escoja el tipo</option>
      <option value="primera clase">Primera Clase</option>
      <option value="segunda clase">Segunda Clase</option>
    </select>
    <input placeholder="Escriba su número de libreta militar" id="libreta" name="libreta" tabindex="7" >
  </label>
</div>
```

PD: La etiqueta `</br>` es incorrecta. Debes usar `<br>` o `<br/>`.

Answer (score 0):

Veo que estas usando `jquery` existe la función `show` para mostrar un div oculto y `hide` para volver a ocultarlo, tu solución seria detectar cuando se haga click sobre el `input` de SI O NO, y mostrar con show el contenido oculto, prueba el siguiente código:

```js
$('.view_check').on('click', function(){ 
    cambiar(this)
  }
)
$('.view_check').on('change', function(){ 
    cambiar(this)
  }
)

function cambiar(item){
  let ref = item.getAttribute('data-ref')
  let swhicher = $(item).parent().parent().find('.view')
  swhicher.find('.view_hide').hide()
  if(item.nodeName == "SELECT"){
    ref = $(item).find('[data-ref]:checked').attr('data-ref')
  }
  if(ref != null ){
    $('.view_hide[data-ref="'+ref+'"]').show()
  }
}
```

```css
.view_hide{
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="view">
  <div class="view_show">
    <label>Tiene libreta Militar</label>
    <label><input type="radio" name="foo" class="view_check" data-ref="hide-1">SI</label>
    <label><input type="radio" name="foo" class="view_check" >NO</label>
  </div>
  <div class="view_hide" data-ref="hide-1">
     <h1>HOLA :p</h1>
     <div class="view">
     <div class="view_show">
      <select class="view_check">
        <option>PRIMERA</option>
        <option data-ref="hide-2">SEGUNDA</option>
      </select>
     </div>
     </div>
     <div class="view_hide" data-ref="hide-2">
         hola mundo
     </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Es que asi lo tengo originalmente pero quiero hacerlo un poco mas global,porque son varios formularios y el ideal es usarlo para varias paginas a la vez.

Comment: ¿A qué te refieres con eso @NixonAndreBohorquezFernande? No fue algo que comentaras desde el inicio de tu pregunta.

Comment: jejeje @FernandoTorres perdon falto especificar ese punto